# sed command inside comment block executes

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a bash script where I have commented a bulk of codes. But the sed command inside the comment block is getting executed. Please find the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo OFF
set -vx
<<COMMENT1
echo "hello 1"
build_label='##BUILD_LABEL##'
build_branch_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed 's/\_[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}\_[0-9]\{2\}\_[0-9]\{4\}\_\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,2\}//g')
build_branch_tag_wus="$build_branch_tag"_
build_date_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed 's/$build_branch_tag_wus//g')
build_path=http://zoho-build3/products/appcreator/webhost/$build_branch_tag/${build_date_tag}/
echo $build_path
echo "hello 2"
COMMENT1
echo "hello World!!!"
```

Any error on the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really a comment block. It's a here document. To better simulate a real comment block, use `<<'COMMENT1'` with single quotes. This will prevent `$(...)` commands from being executed, ignoring all special characters inside the here document.

```
<<'COMMENT1'
echo "hello 1"
build_label='##BUILD_LABEL##'
build_branch_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed 's/\_[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}\_[0-9]\{2\}\_[0-9]\{4\}\_\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,2\}//g')
build_branch_tag_wus="$build_branch_tag"_
build_date_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed 's/$build_branch_tag_wus//g')
build_path=http://zoho-build3/products/appcreator/webhost/$build_branch_tag/${build_date_tag}/
echo $build_path
echo "hello 2"
COMMENT1
```

My preference is to use `#` for all comments, though. It's direct, foolproof, and gets syntax highlighted correctly in any editor.

```
# echo "hello 1"
# build_label='##BUILD_LABEL##'
# build_branch_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed 's/\_[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}\_[0-9]\{2\}\_[0-9]\{4\}\_\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,2\}//g')
# build_branch_tag_wus="$build_branch_tag"_
# build_date_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed 's/$build_branch_tag_wus//g')
# build_path=http://zoho-build3/products/appcreator/webhost/$build_branch_tag/${build_date_tag}/
# echo $build_path
# echo "hello 2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Simple and Clean

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not commenting. What you are doing is a multiline string, and bash does what it should: it replaces

```
$(command)
```

by the output of `command`, hence executing the code.

If you want to comment out code, let the lines start with `#`.